# turning Scientific notation off for only axis() in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering if **scientific notations** can be **turned off "locally"** within the `axis()` command in R?

**Below** is my **R code:**

```
plot(1,1, type = "n", xlim = c(0,1.5), ylim = c(.1, 100000), ann=F,bty="n",yaxt="n")

axis(side=2, at = 10^(-1:5) )  ## HERE CAN I TURN SCIENTIFIC NOTATION OFF ##
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you would like to do is turning it off while writing labels, like below:

> axis(side=2, at = 10^(-1:5),label=c(format(10^(-1:5),scientific=FALSE) ))

Comment: Hi Parvin, I believe it's about the scale, 0.1, 1 and 10 are all clustered together, and there's only space to show first label. This will give me more labels, but the ideal way is to do log scale, `axis(side=2, at = 10^(-1:5),label=c(format(10^(-1:5),scientific=FALSE)),las=1)`

Comment: I had to ask something close to that but anyways got my answer, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

There's not something built in to `axis` to let you temporarily disable scientific notation. Here are a couple options:

```
# option 1: set the option and then reset it:
dsp = getOption("scipen")
options(scipen = 22)
axis(side=2, at = 10^(-1:5)) 
options(scipen = dsp)

# option 2: use format() to explicitly format the labels
plot(1,1, type = "n", xlim = c(0,1.5), ylim = c(.1, 100000), ann=F,bty="n",yaxt="n")
labs = 10^(-1:5)
axis(side = 2, at = labs, labels = format(labs, trim = T, scientific = F))
```

`format` is a very powerful and flexible formatter - it has may options documented at `?format`. Here, for example, you might also be interested in setting `drop0trailing = T`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't completely run my code (didn't reset the scipen option) and thought the `scientific = F` was unnecessary.