# Y axis not showing values correctly R plot

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering what is the **fix** **for my Y axis** in my plot below? Y axis is supposed to be comprised of of SEVEN values (**.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 1000000**)? But they don't show correctly on the plot?

Here is my R code?

```
plot(1, 1, type = "n", xlim = c(0,1.5), ylim = c(.1, 100000), ann=F,bty="n",yaxt="n")

axis(side=2, at = 10^(-1:5),label=c(format(10^(-1:5),scientific=F) ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the y axis as a logarithmic scale with the `log="y"` parameter:

```
plot(1, 1, type = "n", xlim = c(0,1.5), ylim = c(.1, 100000), ann=F, bty="n", log="y", yaxt="n")
axis(side=2, at = 10^(-1:5),label=c(format(10^(-1:5),scientific=F) ) )
```

Comment: within the `axis()` is there a way to **selectively** control the number of digits. For example, can I have **2 digits for non-integers** and **ZERO digits for the integers** on my current X axis?

Comment: I mean the X axis which goes from 0 to 1.5?

Comment: You could creating the labels outside the function with sometime like: x<-c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5), and  `newlabels <- ifelse(x==floor(x), format(x, digits=0), format(x, digits=1))`  I wouldn't recommend it based on presentation style but it could work.

Answer (score 2):

I actually saw you left comment on your last question, so I also added a comment there. It's problem with the scale. 0.1, 1 and 10 are all clustered together, because there's only space to show first label. This code will give me more labels, but the ideal way is to do it in log scale:

```
axis(side=2, at = 10^(-1:5),label=c(format(10^(-1:5),scientific=FALSE)),las=1)
```

Comment: could you please help me find the question which you say I left a comment on?

Comment: @parvin, you mean this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992434/turning-scientific-notation-off-for-only-axis-in-r-plot/41992536#41992536

Answer (score 1):

The axis function tries very hard not to have overlapping labels and the rule of no-overlap includes a margin of whitespace, so you can start to see a difference in number of labels that will fit as you reduce the `cex.axis`:

```
axis(side=2, cex.axis=0.7, at = 10^(-1:5),label=c(format(10^(-1:5),scientific=F) ))
axis(side=2, cex.axis=0.6, at = 10^(-1:5),label=c(format(10^(-1:5),scientific=F) ))
```

Comment: within the `axis()` is there a way to **selectively** control the number of digits. For example, can I have **2 digits** for non-integers and **ZERO digits** for the integers on my current X axis?

Comment: I could imagine something like:  sub("\\.00","", as.character( round( y , 2)

Comment: Yes. As the argument to "labels"